# Return a result set when a look up table is used for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a simple player profile website and am running into a problem with my SQL.

I have a player table and a previous clubs table.  As this is a many-to-many relationship, I am using a look up table (player previous clubs) between the player and previous clubs table.

This all seemed to be working fine until I ran my sql which looks like this:

```
SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, age, position, height, weight, previousclubs.name AS previousclubs, satscore, gpa
FROM player 
INNER JOIN playerpreviousclubs
ON player.id = playerid
INNER JOIN previousclubs
ON previousclubid = previousclubs.id
```

The problem is that if a player has more then one previous club, then all of the information (apart from the previous club) is duplicated so I end up with something like this.

**RESULT SET 1**

```
Name: John Smith
Age: 23
Previous Clubs: Arsenal
```

**RESULT SET 2**

```
Name: John Smith
Age: 23
Previous Clubs: Reading
```

***What I would like it to do is the following:***

**RESULT SET 1**

```
Name: John Smith
Age: 23
Previous Clubs: Arsenal, Reading
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is currently happening please and how I go about rectifying it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use GROUP BY combined with aggregate function in order to achieve wished behaviour (i.e. you need to "aggregate" n-tuples retrieved from DB, that's why the functions are called aggregate :-)). Choice of aggregate function depends on RDBMS you are using, for example:

MySQL:

```
SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(previousclubs.name)
FROM player
INNER JOIN playerpreviousclubs ON player.id = playerid
INNER JOIN previousclubs ON previousclubid = previousclubs.id
GROUP BY player.id, player.name
```

PostgreSQL (v8.4 and higher):

```
SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, array_agg(previousclubs.name)
FROM player
INNER JOIN playerpreviousclubs ON player.id = playerid
INNER JOIN previousclubs ON previousclubid = previousclubs.id
GROUP BY player.id, player.name
```

Comment: Hi Miljen,  

Thanks.  It works perfectly as an SQL statement in it's own right but I need to output that and am currently storing that value in an Array:  

$profiles[] = array(  
 'id' => $row['id'],   
 'name' => $row['name'],  
 'previousclubs' => $row['previousclubs'],  
);  

What value do I need to substitute in for what is currently in bold below?  

'previousclubs' => $row['**previousclubs**'],  

Before in my SELECT statement I had:  

$sql = 'SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, age, position, height, weight, previousclubs.name AS previousclubs, satscore, gpa, link  

Thanks

Comment: Arr MySQL doesn't like GROUP_CONCAT(previousclubs.name) AS previousclubs, it requires GROUP_CONCAT(previousclubs.name) previousclubs, with NO 'AS'.

Comment: Glad to help and glad that you succeeded to find redundant 'AS' by yourself :)